# How to control laptop lid behaviour in Debian 12 in XFCE

Tags: systemd, power-management, laptop, hibernate, acpid

I have recently installed Debian 12 amd64 on a Lenovo IdeaPad 100s. There seem to be a problem with the laptop lid, in paricular I do not find where the behaviour the system should take is set.

In `xfce-power-manager` gui I have set to "Do nothing". Still when I close the lid the system goes to hibernation. After I reopen the lid it goes in a strange mode in which it is not fully out of hibernation in the graphical session. Still the system is "awake enough" that I can go in the second log in (CTRL-ALT-F2) and log in text mode and reboot.

I have tried to chance "Do nothing" in other settings, but the system always does the same, as if `xfce-power-manager` were not really setting anything.  I have tried to modify by hand `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` changing the lines

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
```

leaving the rest fully commented as I found it

```
...
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
...
```

After restarting the service `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` and even after rebooting the behavior of the closure of the lid did note change. I doubt `systemd-logind` is doing anything here because all options are listed as `inactive` because `systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`
returns

```
○ sleep.target - Sleep
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sleep.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

○ suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

○ hibernate.target - System Hibernation
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hibernate.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

○ hybrid-sleep.target - Hybrid Suspend+Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hybrid-sleep.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

At this point I am left to wonder which program is handling the lid ..

Please note that if I use the logout button to do anything like suspend or hibernate or sleep it does it correctly and I am able to wake the machine getting back to a working state. Only when the lid is closed I get this mess ...

Comment: Please run `xev` then close the lid to see what keycode closing the lid is generating.

Comment: I do not see any special event from the closing of the lid. `xev` seems associated to events on the window manager, not system events. I have redirected xev output to a file and really see nothing. The lid is not a button, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: My lid generates keycode (`XF86Sleep`) when closed, are you sure you didn't see any?

Comment: It's often useful to see what
[archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management) has on the
subject. It links to
[xfce](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/start) and we can
then see the
[buglist](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/issues/?sort=created_date&state=closed&first_page_size=20).
One of them sounds
[similar](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/issues/202),
with a [workaround](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/715) of
disabling the compositor.

Comment: FYI. I have tried `upower --monitor-detail` but there is really nothing useful, it's just displaying in-depth info on the battery that is discharging.

Comment: For a complete analysis I checked if have installed all the things listed in [https://superuser.com/questions/323484/what-do-the-power-management-tools-in-linux-do-acpi-pm-utils-etc](https://superuser.com/questions/323484/what-do-the-power-management-tools-in-linux-do-acpi-pm-utils-etc). I only have `systemd` and `upower`.  Still, giving `sudo systemctl suspend` I notice that it does al fine, but the Xscreensaver does not get started. Instead it get gets started when I use Xcfe "logout" button.

Comment: At the moment it seems to do not give anything in xev > xev.log and then grep of XF.

Comment: I use `i3lock` and can testify the issue has to do with the screensaver not beign shown. If I type the password I get in and works ok. Of course if one disables the screensaver removes the problem, but this leaves the door open. For clarity, my `systemctl suspend` originally did _not_ include launching the screensaver, so it worked fine!

Comment: @meuh disabling the compositor with `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s false` seems the most simple fix. If you reply to the original question I'd be glad to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often useful to see what
[archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management) has on the
subject. It links to
[xfce](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/start) and the
xfce4-power-manager, and we can then see the
[buglist](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/issues/?sort=created_date&state=closed&first_page_size=20).

One of them sounds
[similar](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/issues/202):

> **suspending by closing the lid freezes graphics after resuming**
>
> using "When laptop lid is closed" = "Suspend"
> ... "Lock screen when system is going to sleep"
>
> When closing the lid and then opening it back up, the screen will be
> frozen with what it should look like without the lock screen activated.

The suggested [workaround](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/715) is
disabling the compositor with

```
 xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s false
```

The issue is linked back to an earlier [issue](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/715) which is still open
(at 15jan2023), where someone with a Lenovo Ideapad on Debian 12 has another
fix that seems to work, creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with just the lines:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```